# AWS SAM template validation error detected during SAM Deploy. Pseudo-param ${AWS::AccountId} not accepted

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

While attempting SAM Deploy, I'm getting the following reject:

```
1 validation error detected: Value 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/Lambda-Exec-And-CloudWatch' at 'role' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: arn:(aws[a-zA-Z-]*)?:iam::\d{12}:role/?[a-zA-Z_0-9+=,.@\-_/]+ (Service:AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException;
```

This occurs when I replace my account ID in the arn role construction for a Lambda function with the pseudo-parameter:  **${AWS::AccountId}**.

This is the Role property of the Function in the YAML template where that happens:

```
Role:
        arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/Lambda-Exec-And-CloudWatch
```

The expected regex expression seems to only accept hard-coded account ID.

If it helps, I'm using Cloud9 as my IDE.

**What am I missing?**

Thanks!

Comment: We probably need !Sub intrinsic function to substitute accountId!  something like `Role: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/Lambda-Exec-And-CloudWatch` Also if role created in same template, we can easily refer to the resource rather than building Arn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we need to use intrinsic function !Sub , [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html#w2ab1c33c28c59c11) are few examples

```
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Role: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/my-lambda-role
```